# Pycharm extension installation

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, flask-mail

I have a problem in installing extenstions like flask-mail when using pip install ; when I wrote the command there is no error but nothing happened .what is the problem?

Comment: what was the command you typed ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Pycharm, an alternative way to install an extension is the following:

1. File --> Settings --> Project: "Your project name" --> Project Interpreter
2. Click the '+' icon and search for 'Flask-Mail'
3. Click Install Package